# Python: TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

```
count = 100

start = input("Welcome to Reign of Terror \n 1-Start Game 2-Highscores")
if start == "2":
    hisc = open("highscore.txt", "a+")
    hisc.write(count,"\n")
```

When I run the code and choose `2`, I get the error

```
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: It says exactly what the error is. Pass a single argument `hisc.write(str(count)+"\n") `will work.

Comment: Please specify your desired output, because I am guessing you will need to read the highscores

Answer (score 7):

Write takes *one* string, not two.

```
if start == "2":
    with open("highscore.txt", "a+") as hisc:
        hisc.write("{}\n".format(count))
```

Also, use `with` so your file gets closed after writing.

Answer (score 3):

@kabanus answered this, thanks!

> It says exactly what the error is. Pass a single argument `hisc.write(str(count)+"\n")` will work." – kabanus

So this is the correct code:

```
hisc.write(str(count)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Add + before "\n"

That means your code will look like

```
hisc = open("highscore.txt", "a+")
hisc.write(count+"\n")
```